# How to add figures from an arraylist together when I've already looped to remove duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, duplicates

A Somehwat annoying problem has cropped up during my attempt at learning Java.

What I'm attempting to do is pull the unique competitors from an ArrayList that contains the competitor, the location and three race times together.

```
  public Play()
    {
    Setup();
    String[][] temp = new String[competitors.size()][8];
    int j = 0;
    double total = 0;
    boolean isFound = false;
    System.out.println("Racer" + "     " + "first venue time");
    for (Event event : events)
    {
       // System.out.println(event.GetCompetitor() + " " + event.GetVenue()  + " " + event.GetSwim()  + " " + event.GetCycle()  + " " + event.GetRun() + " " + (event.GetSwim() + event.GetCycle() + event.GetRun()));
        //System.out.println(event.GetCompetitor());
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i][0] == (event.GetCompetitor().toString()))
            {
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isFound)
        {
            temp[j][0] = event.GetCompetitor();
            temp[j][1] = (Calculation.GetSeconds(event.GetSwim())) + (Calculation.GetSeconds(event.GetCycle())) + (Calculation.GetSeconds(event.GetRun())) + "";
            temp[j][2] = event.GetSwim() + event.GetCycle() + event.GetRun()+"";
            j++;

        }
        isFound = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
       System.out.println(temp[i][0] + "           " + temp[i][1] + "           " + temp[i][2]);

    }
}
```

This successfully pulls back each competitor without duplicating the names, as well as an(uncoverted into seconds) total from a single venue, but I don't know ow or where to loop in order to grab and get the sum of each of the venues that each competitor takes part in

```
John Iceland 15.49 20.3 45.5 81.28999999999999
Amie Iceland 14.3 19.59 36.3 70.19
Dave Iceland 12.21 22.3 41.24 75.75
Archer Iceland 13.3 21.2 38.57 73.07
Sofie Iceland 16.58 24.45 41.19 82.22
Jerry Iceland 21.5 25.5 43.2 90.2
Denise Iceland 14.2 22.53 47.23 83.96000000000001
Stuart Iceland 12.43 26.34 38.26 77.03
Amie Spain 18.47 21.28 51.12 90.87
Jerry Spain 21.02 22.5 50.45 93.97
John Spain 19.48 26.45 52.34 98.27000000000001
Stuart Spain 18.2 24.2 56.55 98.94999999999999
Claire Spain 22.5 27.32 52.23 102.05
Dave Spain 20.07 22.45 56.32 98.84
Denise Spain 19.42 24.09 54.52 98.03
Darren Spain 18.22 23.31 53.12 94.65
Dave England 15.52 19.5 34.4 69.41999999999999
Sofie England 15.2 21.22 33.27 69.69
Archer England 13.39 18.35 34.21 65.95
Denise England 14.2 19.19 31.56 64.95
Amie England 13.59 17.51 30.12 61.22
Darren England 13.5 18.56 30.54 62.6
Claire England 15.12 21.19 34.53 70.84
Jerry England 14.54 20.55 35.31 70.4
John France 17.4 21.2 51.2 89.8
Stuart France 13.01 20.34 52.47 85.82
Archer France 12.25 20.02 49.34 81.61
Amie France 12.21 19.59 48.32 80.12
Darren France 14.5 20.0 48.27 82.77000000000001
Sofie France 13.56 21.3 51.23 86.09
Dave France 14.23 21.02 52.44 87.69
Jerry France 14.01 26.59 50.05 90.65
```

So basically I'm trying to (for example) pull back Johns name(which I have) and the sum of the four venue totals, which is currently beyond me

Any help is appreciated, and if more detail or clarification is needed on this I'll provide as much as I can

Answer (score 0):

Your `event.GetCompetitor().toString()` includes country name ("John Spain", "John England"). This string are differents, that's the reason why your results include duplicates. Change your if condition: `if (temp[i][0] == (event.GetCompetitor().toString()))` and try splitting the string and taking the first word; also, use `equals` to compare strings: `if (temp[i][0].equals(event.GetCompetitor().toString().split(" ")[0]))`

Comment: oh i didnt mention, John and Spain and John and England are seperate.

theyre both pulled and put into the events arraylist from a multidimensional array and retrieved using events.GetCompetitor() and events.GetVenue()

Comment: `event.GetCompetitor();` returns "John England" or "John"? If returns "John England", try using split. In the other case, compare using `if (temp[i][0].equals(event.GetCompetitor()))`. Don't forget to use `equals` and not `==`

Comment: It just returns John event.GetVenue() returns England or Spain

Comment: I've been working on it at the same time and the closest i can get it to working how i want it to is this way
http://i.imgur.com/oUo5FiT.png

At the bottom theres a new small for loop. This works to retrieve the total time for every venue for a single competitor, but only if i enter a specific number into temp[g][0].

Using temp[g][0] gives me the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 error on the line containing that if statement.

Comment: Please, replace this line: `if (temp[i][0] == (event.GetCompetitor()))` and use this: `if (temp[i][0].equals(event.GetCompetitor()))`

Comment: using that like instead of the original gives me

    http://i.imgur.com/M4GH09q.png

the original way it is now gives me

   http://i.imgur.com/g96gbzt.png

Comment: Checking your code, I think you need a HashMap. Check this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Ofmhdkh.png)